# What does "python -m spacy download en" exactly do?

Tags: python

I've seen the Python interpreter help:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

But I'm still not sure what

```
python -m spacy download en
```

does. I thought it is something like

```
import spacy
spacy.download('en')
```

but that seems not to be the case. Where is the code that gets executed?

Comment: The `download en` command line arguments are passed to `spacy` module to handle

Comment: the `-m` flag basically tells python to run a module as a script (it is common to add a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block in the `__init__.py` file of a module to give it special functionality when you run it vs. when you import it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
python -m <module_name> <args>
```

Allows you to run `python __main__.py <args>` , with `__main__.py`being included in your package.
In your case, that would be this one : [Spacy's **main**.py](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/__main__.py)

Comment: Just to make sure: `<args>` is set to `sys.argv`?

Comment: Yes, it is, with a few special considerations. Mostly, `sys.argv[0]` could be wrong, that's why spacy's main force it with `sys.argv[0] = 'spacy'`

Answer (score 0):

You asked: "*Where is the code that gets executed?*"

As previously stated, it gets run in `__main__.py`

What wasn't stated was where the download code actually lives, which is in  `spacy.cli`

I previously had issues downloading `en` from `spaCy` from python (as opposed to the command-line).

This can be achieved by running
`spacy.cli.download('en')`